# Linux packets coming through mirror-port config not seen by `netcat`

Tags: linux, networking

I've setup switch setup for mirror port:

```
mirror-port 4
interface 1
   monitor
   exit
```

This just means anything coming on port 1 mirror to port 4. I've a Linux machine connected to switch's port 4. Linux machine NIC has IP .201. My tcpdump sees udp packet coming for 201:14001. On the same Linux machine if I run nc -lu 14001 it doesn't see any udp packets. I've added following rule ufw allow 14001/udp.

Note that I don't want the Linux machine to talk to outside world (over the same switch). Where in either iptables or Linux kernel my packet gets dropped?

Following things I tried:

- changing `rp_filter` to 0
- Verified that packet's MAC address is same as NIC's
- I'm also aware that `tcpdump` uses raw socket so it will see everything going on NIC  before kernel filters them out.

So my question is where in Linux kernel stack the packet gets dropped?

Comment: Since it is a mirror port, it is likely that packet you see in tcpdump is actually destined for a different port, so destination MAC address in the frame does not match MAC address of your Linux host. If it is the case, the behavior you see is correct, for the network driver it's just a frame on the wire destined for some other computer.

Comment: tcpdump enables promiscuous mode on the interface. Meaning the interface will see and report things that isn't addressed to the interface.

Comment: Yes @PeterZhabin they are same. Updated questions.

Comment: @Zoredache yeah I'm aware of it, its raw socket vs `nc` see things after kernel networking stack gets involved and in my case seems like somewhere in Linux network packet gets dropped

Comment: Since you've tried to disable rp_filter, I assume there's some other interface on the machine with the routing that gets in the way. Did you disable rp_filter completely (setting all.rp_filter to 0) or just on the interface in question (eth1.rp_filter)? For RPF check to be disabled on an interface, the *maximum* value of all and ethX has to be zero, so you should set all.rp_filter to 0 and then selectively enable it to 1 on other interfaces where you still need it.

Comment: Yep all the interface rp_filter set to 0. But I don't think that was necessary as source IP and target IP are in same subnet. source= 192.168.1.1/24 and target is 192.168.1.100/24

Comment: The way rp_filter works, you should detail how you set rp_filter to 0 if it wasn't 0 (usually needed in more than one place). Alternately you could also provide the routing table in the question.